# Catch change event on input field dynamically added to Jquery Datatables table

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling, onchange

I have an ajax call that uses the following code to add some rows to a data table for each record in the response:

```
strAppName = data.Application_Name
maintCost = '<input class="maintCostField" appid="' + data.Application_ID + '" type="text" placeholder="$">';

$('#myReport').dataTable().fnAddData([
    strAppName,
    maintCost,
    etc,
    etc
]);
```

I've tried the following selectors/events to catch changes to the text box, but none of them trigger.  They are in the document.ready section...

```
$(".maintCostField").bind('change',function () {
    val = $(this).val();
    app = $(this).attr('appid');
    alert('Updating app# ' + app + ' with ' + val);
});


$(".maintCostField").on('change',function () {
    val = $(this).val();
    app = $(this).attr('appid');
    alert('Updating app# ' + app + ' with ' + val);
});
```

(I know this one is deprecated)

```
$(".maintCostField").live('change',function () {
    val = $(this).val();
    app = $(this).attr('appid');
    alert('Updating app# ' + app + ' with ' + val);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  I don't see why it's any different than [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) or many others...

**update***
I added the following to the fnDrawCallback event of the datatable and now it works, only it executes as many times as there are forms on the screen.

```
$(".maintCostField").each(function () {
    this.addEventListener("change", function () {
        val = $(this).val();
        app = $(this).attr('appid');
        alert('Updating app# ' + app + ' with ' + val);
    }, true);
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<s>The answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) is actually wrong.</s> (He updated the answer!) You have to bind the event to a parent element because the `input` doesn't exist yet in order to bind the event to.

```
$(document).on('change', '.maintCostField', function() {
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/79gwj/)

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `$(document).on('input', '.maintCostField', function () {`