# can we get input values which are updated only in jquery datatables on a button click?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with ajax data.and in one column with input values.user can update the values in textbox. now my problem is i want to get the only updated textbox values not all inputs in datatble? how can i achieve this...i am new to the jquery datatables..please ca anyone help me...

```
var table = $('#tbl_AttendanceTracking').DataTable();

var value = table.cell(0, 13).nodes().to$().find('input').val();

var allRows = $("#tbl_AttendanceTracking").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

i have tried above code..but it giving first roew....

thank you guys...i found a solution from here
[Catch change event on input field dynamically added to Jquery Datatables table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225336/catch-change-event-on-input-field-dynamically-added-to-jquery-datatables-table)

Comment: Please provide the code for the table. it is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you guys for your reply....i found a solution for this from this link 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225336/catch-change-event-on-input-field-dynamically-added-to-jquery-datatables-table

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Even you can choose according to your requirement.

```
var table = $('#tbl_AttendanceTracking').DataTable();

$('#tbl_AttendanceTracking tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log(table.row( this ).data() ); // Row Data
    console.log(table.cell( this ).data() );// Cell Data


} );
```

[DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())
[Cell Data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())

Comment: that will give row data...but i want only column input values which are updated by the user on a button click .

Answer (score 0):

I guess jQuery `Datatable` doesn't provide any option to keep a track on edited tables.

But it does provide events like `preEdit/postEdit` for any customization.

So may be you can write your own logic to store all rows(by index) which are being edited.

This links might help

[Inline Editing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/submitData.html)

Other option is to get cell click event like this

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    alert( table.cell( this ).data() );
    // your logic here
} );
```