# How do I tagert this button to click inside my handlebars file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to add a click event to the delete button in my index.handlebars file. However, the button doesn't register a click even though I'm targeting the button in my javascript file.
Here's the handlebars code below:

```
        <ul class="collection with-header">
            {{#each Jokes}}
            <li class="collection-item">
                <div>Jokes: {{joke}} {{username}}
                    <button type="submit" data-id="{{id}}" class="waves-effect waves-light btn userdelete" method="delete">delete the joke</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
            <h4></h4>
        </ul>
```

Here's the click event in the javascript file:

```
        $(".userdelete").on("click", function () {
            const idToDelete = $(this).data("id");
            console.log("click");
            $.ajax({
                url: `/api/Jokes/${idToDelete}`,
                method: "DELETE"
            }).then(function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```

What am I doing wrong? The console.log "click" doesn't even appear in the browser console. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you 100% JQuery is installed properly?

Comment: Yes. I have other buttons on my page that work using the same syntax. It's really strange that this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the .userdelete element being generated dynamically - the element doesn't exist yet, so you can't bind anything to it. Try binding it to a parent element like this:

```
$(".collection").on("click", ".userdelete", function() { /* ... */ });
```

For more information, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225336/catch-change-event-on-input-field-dynamically-added-to-jquery-datatables-table/16225561#16225561)